# Create a mate that allows a part to move within a specified distance from another part

Tags: solidworks

Can I create a mate in solidworks that allows for a part to move up and down but stop at a certain distance from another part?

I have an L-bracket mated to an aluminum rod (black). If it is possible I would like the whole black rod and L-bracket combo to move up but not exceed a certain distance from that horizontal rod below the L-bracket. This mate should be defined from one of edges of the horizontal rod and the bottom side of the L-bracket.

Is this possible?

[image: Pic1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at some of the advanced mates. For example limit mates : https://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/t_Limit_Mates_SWassy.htm

I reckon that'll do what you need. Or you can get even fancier by defining a mate along a path. Good luck :
https://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/t_Path_Mate_SWassy.htm

https://help.solidworks.com/2018 is your friend!

Comment: Yep. Limit mate is correct. To get one, make sure the part is in the middleish of its range of motion, select your two items (two parallel faces will work best), click the mate button, click distance mate, and then the advanced drop-down - this will automatically convert your distance to a limit. Then just type in the outer boundaries and you're away :)